# Fail to connect to james server localhost

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, james

I'm trying to connect to James server localhost, but I'm getting an exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port:25;
 nested exception is:
            java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1545)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:453)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)      
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172) 
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121) 
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
            at mail.main(mail.java:78)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:267)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
            at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1511)
            ... 7 more
```

The directory structure of my James Server is:

```
C:\apache-james-2.3.2
|
|
|
|------C:\apache-james-2.3.2\james-2.3.2
|
|------C:\apache-james-2.3.2\javamail-1.4.2
|
|------C:\apache-james-2.3.2\jaf-1.0.2
```

Here's the code, which is throwing an exception:

I've not changed anything in the config file  of james-2.3.2 subdirectory, then why I'm 
getting that exception?

Here's the code, which is throwing an exception:

```
// imports omitted
public class mail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "blue@localhost";
        String from = "red@localhost";
        String subject = "Hello";
        String body = "What's up";
        if ((from != null) && (to != null) && (subject != null) && (body != null)) {
            try { // we have mail to send
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.host", "localhost");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.debug", "true");
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("red", "red");
                    }
                });
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                Address[] add = { new InternetAddress(to) };
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, add);
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
                message.setText(body);
                Transport.send(message);
                System.out.println(" Your message to " + to + " was successfully sent.");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the console output for james?  try `./james start console`.  also: `./james help`.  I've found that James needs root privileges, run with sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is saying that localhost is unreachable.  I expect that your machine does not have its loopback network address (localhost / 127.0.0.1) correctly configured.

EDIT: I assume that you are running the client and server on the same machine.  If not, you cannot use localhost / 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I'm running the client and server on the same machine; could you tell me how can I configure loopback network address? I've no idea about how to configure it for James Server.

Comment: Actually ... questions like that are better asked on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

I always try to telnet to port 25 on the mailhost, to check if the server can be reached. Try to connect to 127.0.0.1 to check if James is accepting incoming connections. I presume you have checked the logs of James for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the IP address 127.0.0.1 instead of the hostname 'localhost' - maybe DNS lookup on your machine is not set up properly, so that it doesn't know what the name 'localhost' means.

Open the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and make sure it contains a line like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Also, try switching off your firewall or anti-virus software.

Answer (score 0):

- try to start apache james as root user in linux or start as
  Administrator on windows. and check the server is successfully
  started or not on james-server.log file in logs folder
- add the host name on your hosts file

  ```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
  ```
- file placed

  ```
  on linux /etc/hosts
  on windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
  ```
- and restart your server.